# How to avoid circular reference in OOP Javascript?

Tags: object-oriented, javascript, object-oriented-design, entity

I have a problem while working with entity framework in JavaScript. I have two classes Table and Column

```
Class Table {
Columns: Column[]
}

Class Column {
Parent: Table
}
```

Everything works fine until I use function toJSON which I implemented for Base class (both Table and Column inherit from Base). This function just simply go through all properties of an instance and parse it to JSON string. This is for persistence purpose. But toJSON in this case will cause a forever loop from Column to Table and back to Column.

Any expert out there could help me on this?

Comment: In general, try to avoid objects lower in a hierarchy knowing about objects higher up. Circular dependencies are pretty nasty. Does a column REALLY need to know which table "owns" it?

Comment: Why does `Column` need a reference to its parent in the first place? If it doesn't need one, then just don't give it one. If you think it does need one, then we'll need to know why in order to give you a more useful answer than "don't do that".

Comment: @Ixrec in `Column` class I have a `build` function which return a string by combining table and column like `"tableA.colB"`. That why column need to know what table it belong to.These entities are used for building SQL statement.

Comment: instead of a table reference would a simple tableName string suffice?

Comment: See this answer on stack overflow: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22765606/441899

Comment: Just wondering, has anybody done this the opposite way: have column point to table but table doesn't point to column?  "Feels" very weird, and my initial thoughts are that it doesn't work very well, but this *would* fix the circular reference.  For all I know there is some strange layering pattern that does this - I've seen weirder.  :-)

Answer (score 3):

From what you've described, you don't need a circular reference at all, so the best thing you can possibly do is get rid of it completely.

> in Column class I have a build function which return a string by combining table and column like "tableA.colB". That why column need to know what table it belong to.These entities are used for building SQL statement.

This is a sign that your `build` function does not belong on the Column class. Think about it: Why is a single Column in your database the object responsible for building part of an SQL statement? You probably want to do the SQL building in an entirely separate class that's actually designed for that purpose.

```
class SQLBuilder {
    build: function(table, column) {
        return ... + table.name + "." + column.name + ...;
    }
}
```

If for some reason this isn't an option, there are tricks you can resort to like storing the name of the parent table instead of a direct reference (which has most of the downsides of a real circular reference other than "breaking" toJSON), or implementing custom serialization logic (which is really tedious and error-prone code to maintain), but you shouldn't do things like that unless you have a very good reason to.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way, as mentioned in comments, is to remove the `Parent` reference from `Column` as mentioned in the comments.  You can almost certainly recode to provide both the table and column as a pair (instead of just the column) wherever needed.

The next easiest way is to change the content of the `Parent` in `Columns` from an object reference to an id of some sort, whether an integer whose value corresponds to an index into an array of tables, or a string that holds the unique id or name of the table.  This means your usages of `column.Parent`, if they need access to the whole table, will need to be wrapped in a function that understands how to translate the index or string into the parent.

Note that if your table names are unique and that is all you need from `column.Parent`, then perhaps converting these fields from a (circular) reference to another object into a string that identifies the name of the table will work best for you.

The next method is to provide a custom `toJSON()` for `Column` types so that they alter the `Parent` field for serialization, alter it from a reference to an index or string as per the above; this will then only happen during `JSON.stringify()` instead of during routine in-memory use of that field.  Of course, to do this you'll also have to create or simulate a `reviver` operation during/after `JSON.parse()` that understands the references and converts them back to the objects.

Comment: I've tried your last suggestion **custom toJSON**. But from there my next issue comes. toJSON is the way that I store entity into database, before this issue i just pass JSON string to server side. Now i think need to pass the `parent` content also, this i don't really satisfied.

Comment: Ok, try the middle solution, parent as number/string id instead of as object.